# PopUp Form failed but in JsFiddle, it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My pop up form is working very well in JSFIDDLE, but not working in my server. The following code:

I don't forget to put in `<head>`:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/loginPopUp/jquery_popup.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/loginPopUp/jquery_popup.css"></script>
</head>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="topRight-link">
        <li><a href="#"> Register </a></li>
        <li id="popUp-login"><img src="">Login</li>
</ul>

<div id="login-PopUp-box">
    <form class="form" action="#" id="login">
        <h3>Login Form</h3>
        <label>Username : </label>
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="john.wick@yahoo.com"/>
        <label>password : </label>
        <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="************"/>
        <input type="button" id="loginbtn" value="Login"/>
        <input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#login-PopUp-box {
    display:none;
}
```

Lastly, Script is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#popUp-login").click(function() {
        $("#login-PopUp-box").css("display", "block");
    });
</script>
```

And here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/02usbrhm/1/).

The code in both server and jsfiddle are totally the same. I tried to view source page in the browser, and the files for `<head>` are staying there. But it's not working in my server. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Write your function as below**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         $("#popUp-login").click(function() {
            $("#login-PopUp-box").css("display", "block");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ahhhh! i forgot to put `function`. I have used to try in Jsfiddle. Thanks mate!

Comment: Hey @Prog, when it pops up, I still can click other link outside the pop-up. Is there anyway to disable it? Thanks

Comment: @Anthosiast - for that you have to use `model popup` http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 1):

JSfiddle is adding JS with onload - so that should work -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $("#popUp-login").click(function() {
        $("#login-PopUp-box").css("display", "block");
    });

});
```

Comment: Hey @nettutvikler, when it pops up, I still can click other link outside the pop-up. Is there anyway to disable it? Thanks

Comment: Hi, as Prog replied - you "must" use modal for "modal" behaviour - so not allowing clicking outside modal (dialog fn with modal: true, setting should do it)

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code below. Replace your $("#login-PopUp-box").css("display", "block");

```
$("#login-PopUp-box").show()
```